# $\phi(p^k)=p^k-p^{k-1}$ function, don't get 1 step of proof

Tags: abstract-algebra

Hi I have some problem with 1 step of proof

$\phi(p^k)=p^k-p^{k-1}$

So we know $p^k$ is only devided by multiples of p.

The set of multiples of p looks $\{p,2p,3p,...,p^k-p\}$ but i don't why the number of these elements is equal $p^{k-1}$. Could someone explain me that?

Comment: You forgot $p^k$ itself (or $0$ if you prefer), which is a multiple of $p$.  Namely all $jp$ for integers $j$ from $1$ to $p^{k-1}$.

Comment: @asd123456, you can now see an example with the application: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3551322/find-all-the-primes-s-t-phi-leftq3-right-2-phi-leftq2-right-q3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The set of multiples looks like $\{1p,2p,...,(p^{k-1}-1)p,p^{k-1}p\}$ which clearly has $p^{k-1}$ elements.

Comment: I don't get it can u explain me more.I know it's probably stupid but I'm tired and i don't see that.

Comment: The set $\{1,2,...,p^{k-1}\}$ has $p^{k-1}$ elements, now multiply all of them by $p$ to get the set of multiples of $p$.

Answer (score 0):

For $p^k$, we know $0, p, 2p...$ are all multiples of p. This occurs every $p$th number. So out of total $p^k$ numbers, we have $\frac{p^k}{p}=p^{k-1}$ numbers.