# Find all the primes s.t.: $\phi\left(q^3\right)-2\phi\left(q^2\right)=q+3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, totient-function

> Find all the primes $q$ s.t.:
>
> $$\phi\left(q^3\right)-2\phi\left(q^2\right)=q+3$$

My attempt:

$$\phi\left(q^3\right)-2\phi\left(q^2\right)=q+3$$
$$q^3-q^2-2q^2+2q=q+3$$
$$q^3-3q^2+q-3=0$$
$$(q-3)(q^2+1)=0$$
$\implies$ $q=3$ is the only prime solution.

Is this correct?

Comment: There's a typo in the third equation. The constant should be $-3$.

Comment: @ThomasShelby, thank you for correction!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that’s correct. $ $